# How to access via WebDAV without clicking "Open in Explorer View"

Tags: authentication, claims-based-auth, webdav

We were successful at having WebDAV access to a Sharepoint Site on Office 365.

The issue is that this only works after the users clicks "Open in Explorer View" at least once. Then when the session runs out (sign out + restart) accessing via Microsoft explorer will stop working for authentication reason.

I've found the awesome Powershell script  http://www.lieben.nu/liebensraum/onedrivemapper/ and it works fine with the personal onedrive space.

Any idea how we can authorize windows without having to click "Open in Explorer View"?

Comment: I've updated the powershell script you've linked to above, it now fully supports mapping Sharepoint Online libraries directly.

Comment: @Jos thanks a ton again. I discovered that using the "un-protected mode" from IE whil logging in makes the difference. Feel free to post that as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do your users access SharePoint via FQDN (e.g. http://sharepoint.company.com)? Then you have to add the URL of the SharePoint to a registry key called AuthForwardServerList to get your clients authenticated automatically.

See [this MS support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943280) for more details on this behavior.

I would recommend you to test this on one client and then roll out the registry-change via GroupPolicy to all affected clients.

Comment: Here we use company.sharepoint.com. thanks for pointer I check if this helps.